# Variable substitution for fts search in sqlite3 with python3

Tags: python, sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

I am using the fts5 extension of sqlite3 to search through my SQLite database in python3. I know how to use fts5 with a hardcoded query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable MATCH 'columnName : "hardcodedstring"'
```

But I can't figure out how to substitute a variable into this search. I have tried the `?` syntax that can normally be used to substitute variables into a SELECT statement in python for SQLite, but that does not seem to be working.

What I need is code that will allow me to substitute a query held in a variable into a SELECT statement with fts search like the one above.

**Difference From Other Question:** This question is different because I am using the fts5 extension and NOT the `LIKE` clause; the LIKE clause is completely DIFFERENT. The question mark syntax does not seem to work for fts as it does for the LIKE clause.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code you're trying to use.

Comment: I don't know how to do variable substitution; that's why I am asking!

Comment: I figured out how to do it! Can someone please unmark the question as a duplicate so that I can answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Variable substitution into such a statement can be easily done with the peewee orm module. This link provides a thorough explanation: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-sqlite-full-text-search-with-python/
This is a link to the docs of the module: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/